# Usar modelo de Activity padrão do Android para alternar entre edição e visualização

Tags: android

Tenho uma `activity` que serve para exibir o Perfil do usuário, então ela lista informações sobre este usuário. Quero saber como faz aquele padrão já adotado pelo Android de na ActionBar ficar um ícone para editar as informações e o que era `TextView`, virar `EditText`, isso é em uma `activity` só ou duas?

Answer (score 4):

no caso, para você 'trocar' um textview por edittext você pode usar um ViewSwitcher

Exemplo:

-- LAYOUT

```
<ViewSwitcher
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/my_switcher"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/clickable_text_view"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="TextViewClicked"
            android:text="@string/some_value" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/hidden_edit_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/some_value" >
        </EditText>
    </ViewSwitcher>
```

-- ACTIVITY

```
public void TextViewClicked() {
    ViewSwitcher switcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.my_switcher);
    switcher.showNext(); //or switcher.showPrevious();
    TextView myTV = (TextView) switcher.findViewById(R.id.clickable_text_view);
    myTV.setText("value");
}
```

porém, quando se trata de muitas informações eu nunca cheguei a avaliar se essa solução impacta na performance.

particularmente, na maioria dos casos, eu instancio direto um edittext no modo 'Enable:false' e quando aciona o button para editar eu habilito a edição do edittext 'Enable: true'.